# Get active directory computers of specific group using "memberOf" attribute using C#

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to get all the computer names which are in the active directory "Standard" group. The AD tree looks like this:

[image: adtree]

I tried to get the computers using "memberOf" attribute (I found the attributes on this page: http://www.kouti.com/tables/userattributes.htm). So I have this code:

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "bbad.lan"))
{
    using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
    {
        foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
        {
            DirectoryEntry entry = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;

            if (entry.Properties["memberOf"].Value == "Computer")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("aaa: " + entry.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After debugging this code because it didn't show any message boxes I found out that the "memberOf" attribute returns some strange strings. I used `MessageBox.Show(entry.Properties["memberOf"].Value.ToString());` to get the value of "memberOf" attribute. This is what I get:

```
1. MsgBox: CN=Gäste,CN=Builtin,DC=bbad,DC=lan
2. MsgBox: System.Object[]

etc.
```

There are much more MsgBoxes but every box is like this.

After looking in our active directory I couldn't figure out the order the entries gets displayed. And I noticed that nothing like "Computer" (see the image) shows up.

**Conclusion:** I just want to get the computers in `bbad.lan > Computer > Standard` but the results of my code confuse me so I'm quite perplexed now.

Suggestion appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following using the computer principal class:

```
        try
        {
            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext (ContextType.Domain, "ADDomain", "OU=Standard,OU=Computer,DC=bbad,DC=lan");
            PrincipalSearcher searcher  = new PrincipalSearcher(new ComputerPrincipal(ctx));

            foreach (ComputerPrincipal compPrincipal  in searcher.FindAll())
            {
                //DO your logic
            } 


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

Comment: I replaced "ADContainer" with the following string: `LDAP://OU=Standard,OU=Computer,DC=my,DC=domain`. Or how has the container to look like?

Comment: Yes that's correct, if you dont specify the containter it will search the entire Active Directory Domain.

Comment: Mh okay, but if I do this I get the following exception: `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalOperationException: Unknown error (0x80005000)`. You know this exception? It says the exception occurs on this line: `PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new ComputerPrincipal(ctx));`

Comment: I've edited my code, please check how I added the container. Jst make sure that these two DC=my,DC=com are correct because in your pic you've scrap them off.

Comment: I've edited my question so you can see the original image. So it should be correct using `PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "bbad.lan", "LDAP://OU=Standard,OU=Computer,DC=bbad,DC=lan");` right?

Comment: Remove "LDAP://". Check my edit and also make sure the ADDomain is correct as well.